# The second longest side of a quadrilateral is 11cm such that all of its sides are integral. Find its longest side.

Tags: geometry

The second longest side of a quadrilateral is $11 \text {cm}$ such that the lengths of all of its sides are distinct integers. What would be the length of the longest side?

This was the very first question in kvpy.

I think this was the question that made me turn to chemistry in the examination..

In here I don't even know if the question is incorrect or correct and furthermore, how to even proceed?

POST EDIT.

I am sure that distinct sides were not included in the question but then also for arguments sake i think its better to take it as distinct.

Comment: I can construct a rectangle whose short side is 11cm and whose long side is  $10^{834873487}$cm....

Comment: i think the integral condition is important here..i just editted to include it...sorry for inconvinience

Comment: Also, sides are supposed to be distinct. Suggested Edit.

Comment: let $a > 11 > c > d$ be the 4 sides. Since $c, d$ are distinct integers, $c \le 10$ and $d \le 9$. Now $a < 11 + c + d$, this means..

Answer (score 3):

The answer is $29$.

Let $a>b>c>d$ be the sides of the quadrilateral. Then $b=11$. The largest possible value for $c$ is $10$, and so the largest possible value for $d$ is $9$.

By the triangle inequality, $a < b + c + d =30$, so $a = 29$.

(If $a = 30$, you would get a line instead of a quadrilateral.)

[image]

Comment: +1. I personally believe that degenerate ("flat") quadrilaterals are fair game unless expressly forbidden. (The question has already undergone multiple edits for omitted details, so it's hard to say for sure what the official intent is here.) It's good that you address this possibility.

Comment: 29 was not even in the options

Comment: You recently edited your question saying "distinct sides were not included". Using my solution, can you figure out what the answer would be if sides can have the same lengths?